# sort utility with compound numeric keys

Tags: linux, sort, posix

The documentation for the `sort` utility leads me to a different conclusion about its behavior than what is observed.

Consider the below command:

```
$ sort -k2,1n <<EOF
9 alpha
100 alpha
9 zeta
100 zeta
EOF
```

The secondary sort field being given as the first physical field, with a numeric interpretation, leads me to predict  that `9` would precede `100`.

In actual fact, the result is:

```
100 alpha
100 zeta
9 alpha
9 zeta
```

It would appear that the trailing `n` is not taking the intended effect.

What is lacking in my understanding?

I am running Linux Mint 19.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **-k, --key=KEYDEF**
>    sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> **KEYDEF**  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]  for  **start  and stop position**,

So, 2 is the sorting start position and 1 is the stop position of your sorting. I admit, this is a somehow confusing behavior.

What you want is individual keys:

```
sort -k2 -k1n
```